как правильно обрабатывать не подряд пришедшие запросы с устаревшим токеном?
Всем привет, вопрос не могу отнести к точной теме. У меня есть апи, в который я создал мидлвэйр для проверки токенов ( для того, чтобы понять, запрос от верифицированного пользователя и от какого)..
в особенности фронта входит то, что для отрисовки экрана он делает сразу много ассинхронных запросов.
Проблема возникает, когда ассесс токен устарел:
При получении первого (первого обработанного) запроса, я заменяю ассесс токен и возвращаю его ответом, но другие запросы, которые приходят, отклоняются, тк уже не действительный ассесс, да и отправлен мной новый. мб я чет не так понимаю в реализации?
единственный вариант решения этого я нашел в грейс периоде старого токена, но не думаю, что это хорошая идея

Смысл jwt в том, чтобы он был самодостаточен и не требовал дополнительных действий для проверки себя (например отправки запросов в базу), ваша попытка "заменить" токен противоречит самой сути jwt

Ну а в целом - просто сделать новый токен и не трогать старый токен, давая ему спокойно отработать до истечения его срока действия
